# Page break problem with exsheets: How to avoid this automatically?

Tags: page-breaking, exsheets

I have a problem with exheets and page breaks. The document contains a lot of pictures and multiple exsheets environments as in my MWE below. The problem is that I often get bad looking page breaks as in the my example. I don't want to fiddle with every such problem manually and looking for a global option which makes LaTeX to avoid such bad page breaks automatically. In particular I would prefer in this case (page break just after a line or two of the question text) to move the entire question to a new page if it doesn't fit on the rest of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern,microtype}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2-5]



\begin{question}
  Just a line of text.

  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-0.5ex\relax}
    \lipsum[2]
  \end{minipage}
  \hspace*{1ex}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-0.5ex\relax}
    \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[valign=t,width=\linewidth]{test}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the `\\ ` at the end of the paragraph is always wrong and makes an underfull box warning, and similarly too boxes .5\textwidth wide and a space of 1ex can not fit on a line, if you give latex impossible constraints then latex doesn't really have much of a chance. If questions always fit on one page you can put them in a box.

Comment: Questions doesn't fit always on a page.

Comment: I modified my example to avoid the problems mentioned in your comment.

Comment: so how is tex supposed to know that the paragraph break before the box is not a good place to break, you need to give it a clue.

Comment: The rule could be something like this: If the break would occur after n (say n = 1 or n = 2) lines after the question title, just move the whole question to a new page.

Comment: tricky, easy to say don't break a para before (say) 3 lines but harder to say don't break even after the paragraph if it is short, but even if you put `\nopagebreak` there so it doesn't break, then only the line of text is carried to the next page, leaving the heading on its own which seems like a mis-feature of the excercise environment.  you could use `needspace` package and prepend something like \needspace{.3\textheight} before each question so it throws a page break if more than 70% of the page has been used.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the `exsheets` solutions. Unfortunately, the `needspace` package can't fix it. All the solutions are taken to the end of the chapter, and `\needspace{.3\textheight}` has no effect there.

Comment: Never mind. I just had to put `solution/pre-hook = \needspace{0.1\textheight},` in my `SetupExSheets` option lists.